# dynamically update require path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have local json files and i want to update the paths to these files dynamically in React. For instance, I have

> file1.json
>
> file2.json

inside each json file i have objects.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      user: require('./'),
      userSelected: null,
    };
  handleChange =(e) => {
    var data = './json/' + e.target.value + '.json';
    try{
      this.setState({
        user: require(data), userSelected: e.target.value
        });
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input value={this.state.userSelected} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <h1> {this.state.user.name} </h1>
        you are {this.state.user.age} years old
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

this doesnot work. i get ***not declared as a System.registerDynamic dependency of index.js*** error

I already tried nesting inside function - not working,
import - returns an empty promise,
konfig - not working

i need to access the json data and display it in name and age dynamically with change in state.user

the requirement is to use require function. I cannot use fetch or axios.

Comment: instead of using require path, U can use ajax request, its will helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** 
To solve your issue System.registerDynamic dependency, you have to configure webpack to load json files

```
webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And then the file can be load by

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      user: require('./'),
      userSelected: null,
    };
  handleChange =(e) => {
const value = e.target.value;
  var data = require('json!./${value}.json'); // forward slashes will depend on the file location

    try{
      this.setState({
        user: data, userSelected: e.target.value
        });
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input value={this.state.userSelected} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <h1> {this.state.user.name} </h1>
        you are {this.state.user.age} years old
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work. Same error "not declared as a System.registerDynamic dependency of index.js"

Comment: @Andruraj have you configure webpack?

Comment: you should have webpack.config.js file where you should the the configuration to load json files, and install the loader  see on --> https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of axios to fetch data from the json file.

```js
axios.get('../public/users.json') // JSON File Path
   .then( response => {
     this.setState({
     data: response.data
   });
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: the requirement is to use require function. I cannot use fetch or axios

Answer (score 0):

U are jest getting json data from your local file then use fetch api for that

```
handleChange =(e) => {
    var data = './json/' + e.target.value + '.json';
    fetch(data)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
        user: response, userSelected: e.target.value
        });
  });
  }
```

Comment: the requirement is to use require function. I cannot use fetch or axios.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/7om3w3r4p0 worked for me.
Could dynamically import the files using require module

Comment: the requirement is to use require function. I cannot use fetch or axios.

Answer (score 0):

You could just import the file using `async await`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {},
    userSelected: null
  };
  handleChange = async ({ target }) => {
    const value = target.value;
    var json = `./${value}.json`;
    try {
      const data = await import(json);
      this.setState({
        user: data,
        userSelected: value
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.userSelected} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <h1> {this.state.user.name} </h1>
        you are {this.state.user.age} years old
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work. Same error "not declared as a System.registerDynamic dependency of index.js"

Comment: There is some issue with configuration because it is working for me. [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/yk3x4w7zm9). That is the reason we should bootstrap with create-react-app to avoid configuration issue. Try CRA.

Comment: Its because it goes into catch block and state is not updated, check again, I have updated the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/yk3x4w7zm9)

Comment: ya i noticed that, I'm a beginner, so I dont know where to find and edit what in webpack, because its working in sandbox, but not on my pc localhost. Thanks anyway :)